# Bootstrap jQuery Notify - onClose pass parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I've just implemented bootstrap-notify.js into my asp.net project I have it working and i'm creating the notify from code behind in c#

this is working fine and the alert opens which I have set to delay zero so the user will have to dismiss,

what I wanted to do is when the user dismisses the alert to call a web method to then update the database to say they have closed the alert and this wont re-appear, all this I'm fine with,

my issue is that I need to pass the alert id from code behind/notify to jQuery but it seems the onClose event can't pass parameters

here is my notify create

```
 String sMsg = "";
                sMsg += "$.notify({";
                sMsg += "icon: 'fa fa-plus', ";
                sMsg += "message: 'Schedule Created: " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DSC_DELNAME"].ToString() + " <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Order " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DSC_ORDREF"].ToString() + " Scheduled on " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DSC_DELDATE"].ToString().Replace(" 00:00:00", "") + ", PO " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DSC_CUSREF"].ToString() + " ' ";
                sMsg += "},{";
                sMsg += "delay: 0, onClose: SubmitAlert ";
                sMsg += "});";
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Scheduler Alert", sMsg, true);
```

and the jQuery function that calls the webmethod (if I hard code an alert id here is working fine)

```
    function SubmitAlert(AltID) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxcall.aspx/AlertRead",
        data: '{"AlertID":"' + AltID + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
    });
}
```

so what I ideally need is on this line

sMsg += "delay: 0, onClose: SubmitAlert ";

to do this

sMsg += "delay: 0, onClose: SubmitAlert(AlertID) ";

but this doesn't work, any ideas how I might get around it, there could be multiple alerts on screen at once so it needs to use the alert id on the one that has closed,

this is the function from bootstrap-notify that I think onClose uses

```
if ($.isFunction(self.settings.onClose)) {
            self.settings.onClose.call(this.$ele);
        }
```